# Safe Boot on System.Config is unclickable after moving my windows boot manager to another drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, boot-manager

I moved my windows boot manager from my old drive to another drive. I created a small drive called L: and transfer my boot manager to L: using "bcdboot c:\windows /s l:" command.

Going to the System Configuration, I could no longer checked the safeboot option. Any steps that I missed?

[image]

Checking my drive L: I have this files created.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your new partition is missing data, that your original partition, had which is required for WinRE. Your screenshot makes it appear the checkbox is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Drive L: is just a normal NTFS formatted drive. Windows could not see it. Windows needed the partition to be EFI format.

[image]

The Solution is to create an EFI partition drive. Put a drive letter L:

Then do this command "bcdboot c:\windows /s l:"

After which you can check the safeboot box.

[image]